# Size of compiled vue apps

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have 3.6kb worth of `.vue` component files. Minified vue is 77kb, but when I build them with webpack I end up with a file that's 84kb.

Is this just overhead from translating templates into js? Is it overhead from webpack? Is it just expected to have this kind of overhead for bundling separate JS files?

When I use browserify it gets the file size down to 61kb (Wow) but then it doesn't work. Vue starts up and replaces the template but it's blank, created never gets called.

Comment: If you take a look at the resulting file you'll see a variety of additions from Webpack. A few KB doesn't sound unusual at all. Serve it gzipped and you'll likely shave some of that off.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't make much of a difference percentage wise, but since I'm just serving a single static file it seems a bit redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browserify is a bit smaller, but not much. The 20kb less file size was [a bug in the vue template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify-simple/issues/17)